# How do I make a shader that simulates acrylic paint being smeared on a surface?

Tags: unity, shaders, glsl, hlsl

I know *something* about shaders, I have written some very **basic** shaders. [This](https://github.com/blablaalb/Texture-Projection/blob/main/Assets/Graphics/Shaders/Projection.shader) is the most advanced shader I have written so far.

It's been several days since I conceived the idea of trying to recreate [this shader](https://s4.gifyu.com/images/phone_case_diy.gif), but I still can't wrap my head around on how to approach it.
[I figured out I can hide part of the object by making the texture fully transparent and then, after player moves the brush across the object, project the brush on to the object and reveal that part of the texture.](https://s4.gifyu.com/images/try1.gif)

```
Shader "Custom/Masked Transparent" {
    Properties {
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB) Trans (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _MaskTex("Mask Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }

    SubShader {
        Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
        LOD 200

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Lambert alpha:fade

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        sampler2D _MaskTex;
        fixed4 _Color;

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
        };

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
            fixed4 main_color = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
            fixed4 mask_color = tex2D(_MaskTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
            o.Albedo = main_color.rgb;
            o.Alpha = mask_color.r;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
}
```

But this implementation lacks the perceived height and liquidity you can observe in the original shader . How do I implement the effect of smearing acrylic paint? Any advice, resources, tutorials and maybe there's ready to use assets - anything is welcome! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into shaders that include normal maps for lighting, and heightmap / displacement maps for depth?

Comment: @DMGregory In the last gif the texture [shrinks](https://gifyu.com/image/STa65) and if observe this effect carefully we can spot some mesh deformation [https://i.ibb.co/74sXSdZ/image.png](artifacts). I suppose they used some kind of mesh deformation algorithm? I tried to use displacement map but it didn't look even remotely close to the original effect. I haven't tried to use normal map yet

Comment: You could do it with a mesh, but you could also do it with a displacement map where you run a fluid simulation on the map itself, simulating surface tension/elasticity that tries to pull the paint from cell to cell.